# What is it called when reversing a phrase doesn't mean the same as the original phrase?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What is the rhetorical device/argument called when one says:

> All surgeons are doctors, but not all doctors are surgeons.

Comment: I don't know what the "X Y Z, Z Y X" sentence structure is called in English grammar, but I do know "*all surgeons are doctors, but not all doctors are surgeons*" falls under *syllogism* in the philosophy of logic (and the term can be applied to such logical propositions in *any* language, even formal languages like mathematical notation, or programming code).

Comment: Grammatically, it's two sentences combined into a single sentence by connecting them with a conjunction. Is that the kind of answer you wanted?

Comment: @DanBron The statement is certainly not a syllogism as there is not at least two propositions and a conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Antimetabole and possibly Chiasmus.

http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/antimetabole.htm

Comment: It would be nice to include the definition of each of these words, and possibly an example, in your answer.