# Linked phrases?

Tags: phrases

I am wondering if there is a literary term for the following types of sentences:

"When the going gets tough, the tough get going."

"Money doesn't make you, you make money."

In these phases, the words "going" and "tough" appear twice in the first sentence and "money" and "you"appear twice in the second sentence.

Linked phrases? Contrasting phrases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is it called when reversing a phrase doesn't mean the same as the original phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204015/what-is-it-called-when-reversing-a-phrase-doesnt-mean-the-same-as-the-original) Also [Name of a particular type of verbal riposte.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353654/name-of-a-particular-type-of-verbal-riposte)

Answer (score 2):

This is [Antimetabole](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/figures_speech/antimetabole.htm):

> **Description**
>   Antimetabole is the repetition of a clause, with reversed wording in the second clause.
>   **Example**
>   We eat to live, not live to eat.
>   Ask not what your country can do for you, but what you can do for your country. -- J.F.Kennedy
>   It is not even the beginning of the end but is perhaps, the end of the beginning -- Winston Churchill