# phrase whereby the swapping of words has an entirely new meaning

Tags: phrases

the bottom has fallen from my world
the world has fallen from my bottom

These are examples of ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is it called when reversing a phrase doesn't mean the same as the original phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204015/what-is-it-called-when-reversing-a-phrase-doesnt-mean-the-same-as-the-original) Also related: [Name of a particular type of verbal riposte.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353654/name-of-a-particular-type-of-verbal-riposte)